# go - Handling AJAX POST request

Tags: ajax, http, post, go, request

I setup a middleware and router to handle an AJAX request on path `/api/on` like this

```
http.HandleFunc("/",route.IndexHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/login",route.GoogleLoginHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/auth/google",route.GoogleCallbackHandler)
http.Handle("/dashboard",negroni.New(
            negroni.HandlerFunc(route.IsAuthenticated),
            negroni.Wrap(http.HandlerFunc(route.DashboardHandler)),
))
http.Handle("/api/on",negroni.New(
            negroni.HandlerFunc(route.IsAuthenticated),
            negroni.Wrap(http.HandlerFunc(route.TurnOn)),
))
```

Middleware `IsAuthenticated` allows to jump to the next router if there is a user session in my web, otherwise it will redirect

```
func IsAuthenticated(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {
    session, _ := util.GlobalSessions.SessionStart(w, r)
    defer session.SessionRelease(w)

    if session.Get("profile") == nil {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    } else {
        next(w, r)
    }
}
```

And this is `TurnOn` handler for later process

```
func TurnOn(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := util.GlobalSessions.SessionStart(w, r)
    defer session.SessionRelease(w)

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type")

    fmt.Println(r.URL)
}
```

After I turned on server, I conducted a POST request with JavaScript's client-side code using AJAX, but the console logged nothing. It seems that the `TurnOn` function was not reached even when AJAX request was sent successfully. Did I miss something obviously?

Comment: Did you remember to set the content type on the client to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I did, but it does nothing here. I need to check if it reaches the handler or not, and it doesn't

Comment: So the problem is is that it does not reach your TurnOn function?

Comment: Is your AJAX call returning an error? 404? Timing out? Nothing?

Comment: @Machiel Yes, it seems that it doesn't reach `TurnOn` function

@elithrar No. In JavaScript code I wrote for it to log something in console to notify success. And it does log, which means no error occurs

Comment: Ok so does it reach IsAuthenticated? Have you tried removing IsAuthenticated and seeing if it reaches the code? Could it be you are hitting the redirect? The code looks ok so difficult to add anything of real value

Comment: @Maleck13 It does reach `IsAuthenticated`. Even if I put aside IsAuthenticated and set a sole `TurnOn` handler without `IsAuthenticated` middleware, it still doesn't reach `TurnOn`